# Function similar to Jquery $.grep?

Tags: javascript, date

The grep function in Jquery will take in a json, and return all the parts of a json that pass a test. For example:

```
            var entriesInDateRange = $.grep(timeEntryChartData, function (timeEntryChartData) {
                return timeEntryChartData.Date_Worked >= e.value[0] && timeEntryChartData.Date_Worked <= e.value[1];
            });
// This function will return all time entries that are within the range of e.value.
```

I am looking for a similar function that takes all the strings in the json that look like "2020-12-30T08:11:35.99" and turn them into date objects.

My Json is full of arrays that look like this:

```
Total_Hours: 9.48,
Start_Time:"2020-05-18708:31:48",
 End_Time: "2020-05-18718:00:49"
```

And I would like it to look like

```
Total_Hours: 9.48,
Start_Time: new Date("2020-05-18708:31:48"),
 End_Time: new Date("2020-05-18718:00:49")
```

If such a function does not exist, I think it would be possible to create a function that iterates over the json, and if key == "Start_Time", then cast it to date, but I am looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) can take a "reviver" function that could match strings matching the date format and convert them straight into `Date` objects.

Comment: p.s I suspect the digit seven (7) separating your dates and times is supposed to be a capital "T".

Comment: @derpirscher That does the same as grep. I want to modify the value if it doesnt pass a test, not remove it.

Comment: p.p.s JSON is a serialisation format - once it is parsed into JS primitive values it is no longer JSON.

Comment: @LukedukeAnimations I cite your post 1) "that takes all the strings in the json that look like" => filter , 2)  "turn them into date objects" => map

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for, Post it as an answer and Ill accept it. Also yes, the 7 is supposted to be a T, I used OCR, and totally missed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.parse` can take a [reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) function as a parameter that can be used to transmogrify values as the JSON data is deserialised.

In this case you'd need a function that tests each value to see if it matches the ISO date/time format and returns `new Date(value)` if so, otherwise returning the original value:

```
const iso8601 = /^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\dZ?$/
const reviveToDate = (k, v) => iso8601.test(v) ? new Date(v) : v;

let myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON, reviveToDate);
```